# Why is my button not doing anything?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use HTML to call a function in an external JavaScript file.  The JavaScript file is called "javascript.js".

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
    </script>
    <script
        // Calling the Google Maps API
    </script>

    <script>
        <!-- JavaScript to load Google Maps -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="googleMap"></div> <!--don't have to worry about this -->
        <div id="right_pane_results">hi</div> <!--don't have to worry about this -->
        <div id="bottom_pane_options">
            <button onclick="todaydate()">Try It</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**...and my JavaScript code (something I got from the internet just to test):**

```
function todaydate() {
    var today_date=new Date()
    var myyear=today_date.getYear()
    var mymonth=today_date.getMonth() + 1
    var mytoday=today_date.getDate()
    document.write("<h1>"+myyear+"/"+mymonth+"/"+mytoday+"/h1">)
}
```

On my webpage that I'm running locally, the button is showing, but nothing happens when I click on it.  Is it something to do with my code?

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: if you open up your browser's console, are there any errors? F12 in chrome, firefox, and ie

Comment: put an `alert("something")` at the beginning of your `todaydate` function to see if it's being called

Comment: Typo in `document.write("<h1>"+myyear+"/"+mymonth+"/"+mytoday+"/h1">)`. Should be `document.write("<h1>"+myyear+"/"+mymonth+"/"+mytoday+"</h1>")`

Comment: BTW: Learn to not use `document.write` whenever possible. It brings more problems than gains. With jQuery you could `$('<h1>').append(myyear...).appendTo('body')`, you can do it in plain DOM as well using `document.createElement`, `.innerText` and `document.body.appendChild`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes inside the function. The `>` needs to be inside the quotes and there needs to be a `<` before the `/h1`.

Replace this line:

```
document.write("<h1>"+myyear+"/"+mymonth+"/"+mytoday+"/h1">)
```

with this

```
document.write("<h1>"+myyear+"/"+mymonth+"/"+mytoday+"</h1>")
```

and it should work.

Comment: And what's the second mistake...?

Comment: the line have 2 mistakes, > must be before last quote and the tag h1 must be closed "</h1>"

Answer (score 2):

I guess this has to do with the syntax error you have:

```
document.write("<h1>"+myyear+"/"+mymonth+"/"+mytoday+"</h1>")
```

note how the last quote is after the `>` (and you also forgot the `<` for the closing `h1`)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write("<h1>"+myyear+"/"+mymonth+"/"+mytoday+"</h1>")
```

This works!

Answer (score 1):

As other answer mention syntax issue is in your document.write statement.

Beside this use getFullYear() to get year as [getYear() is Deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

some other practices to make your code cleaner:

- Use semi-colan at end of statement
- Use a good naming convention

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/QR9ug/)

```
function getTodayDate() {
    var todayDate=new Date();
    var myYear=todayDate.getFullYear();
    var myMonth=todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var myDay=todayDate.getDate();
    document.write("<h1>"+myYear+"/"+myMonth+"/"+myDay+"</h1>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zaheer.  I will practice that in the future.